# What is the best way to say that x is of dimension R^n and all x are elements of the set H?

Tags: linear-algebra

To denote the dimension of a variable, we often use $ x \in R^n$ and to say that $x$ is an element of the set $H$ we use $x \in H$. Now I want to combine both things in one expression. What is the best way to do this?

I have never seen it this way: $ x \in H \in R^n$. Is this correct?

My goal is to write something like this: $x \in R^n$ is of dimension $n$ so x can be any value of $R$ with $n$ entries and $H$ is the set that contains some of these $x$ for instance 500 and not all.

Comment: We would write $x \in H \subseteq R^n$ to indicate that $x$ is an element in $H$ and that $H$ is a set of a bunch of stuff inside $R^n$. The symbol $\subseteq$ is read as "is a subset of".

Comment: Also, it is typically written $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @prets this makes sense and sounds good! thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "$H$ is the set that contains all $x$"?

Comment: @LouisPan , I would like to say the following: that x can be a value between 1 and 100 via $x \in \{1,2,...,100\}$ and via $x \in H$ I want to say that all instances of $x$ from $x_1$ to $x_{500}$ are stored in a set $H$.

Comment: @user3352632: What are the elements in the set $H$? Is $H$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @LouisPan yes, H is a subset of $R$ that contains only particular x.

Comment: You should be 100% clear: Is $H$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? They are different things.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in your question. If $x\in\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$, then $x$ is a scalar, not a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can you please write in plain English, what do you really want to say?

Comment: @LouisPan, sorry for confusion. Case 1) I know x is $R^n$. And $H$ is a subset of $R^n$ since $H$ does not contain all combinations of $R^n$. Case 2) $x$ is a scalar ($x \in R$) and I know it can be one of 100 values $\{1, ..., 100\}$, and $H$ probably contains $x$ with all of these 100 values. So $H$ is equal $\{1, ..., 100\}$, i.e. the same set.

Comment: One step at a time: in case 1: "I know $x$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$", you really mean $x$ is **an element** of $\mathbb{R}^n$, correct?

Comment: @LouisPan yes, I mean $x_i \in H$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe that is a better way to express this, what I mean. $x_i$ and $i$ denotes the index of an instance where I have 500 pieces. These 500 are "stored" in a set $H$. and the size/dimension of $x$ is $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $x$ is a vector of size $n$. And these 500 pieces of $x$ that I have are in my understanding a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ since I have not all combinations that exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Sorry for my bad skills. But thanks for your help and support. I hope this is more clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131228/discussion-between-louis-pan-and-user3352632).

Answer (score 1):

Turning the comment into an answer:

We would write $x \in H \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ to indicate that $x$ is an element in $H$ and that $H$ is the set of a bunch of stuff inside $\mathbb R^n$. The symbol $\subseteq$ is read as "is a subset of".

Comment: Thanks, and in case of $x \in \{1,2,...,100\}$ and $x \in H$. I would like to say that $x$ can be any value from 1 to 100 and all instances of $x$ from $x_1$ to $x_{500}$ are stored in a set $H$?

Comment: Your question here is not clear to me. Could you clarify?

Comment: Instead of the infinite $R$ space, now I have just a set of 100 numbers and $x \in R$. So I would say that x can be any of these 100 numbers and all $x$ which is probably all are in the set $H$. Is your formalization also correct in this case?